# Mozilla AFRAME a-frame not able to set offset or repeat for material

Tags: aframe

I have ran across a big problem in AFRAME. In my current project, the user is able to change the scale of a plane with a texture mapped onto it by the press of a button. Of course, I then need to change the tiling (or repeat, how it is called in AFRAME) - but no matter how I try to do it, I can not get the repeat or offset to change. The wierd thing is, when I try to change the materials color, it works fine. I think the problem is that AFRAME is somehow not updating the repeat at runtime?! Maybe I also pass the parameters X and Y in a wrong way?

This is what I tried so far:

```
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material', {color: 'red', offset: {x: 22, y: 22}});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material', {color: 'red', repeat: 12});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material', {color: 'red', repeat: {type: 'vec2', value: {x: 22, y: 22}}});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material', {repeat: {value: {x: 1, y: 1}}});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('repeat', {type: 'vec2', value: {x: 22, y: 22}});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material.repeat', {type: 'vec2', value: {x: 22, y: 22}});
//document.querySelector('#wall-1').setAttribute('material', 'repeat', '{x:22, y:22}');
```

I would be glad for ANY help!

Thanks a bunch & best,
- Max

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug, but this was fixed at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2253

Try this build: https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/64d772a/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip! I got a 404 on that but I downloaded the current aframe-master from the github dist. However, I still can not get it to work. What would be the correct way for setting the attribute? Also, with the newest build I get some bad errors with repeat in general: http://imgur.com/a/qFljS

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to repeat textures when using a-assets on an a-entity.
I could on an a-box, but had to call the .jpg directly inline when using a-entity instead of using the a-assests. I know this takes up more memory, and file space if used a lot, but at least it started working.

Using `<a-box>` for everything worked for me,
as did inline links in `<a-entity>` without using `<a-assets>`.

Here is a small fiddle showing it working:
`https://jsfiddle.net/RonK/tjfwhdsd/16/`